# How to install rawpy libraries?

Tags: python, image-conversion, raw

I am currently working on a project which requires me to convert `RAW` images to `JPEG`, it seems the `rawpy` package ([link](https://pypi.org/project/rawpy/)) is the best option available to me but if you know any better ways to automate the conversion then let me know.

I installed `rawpy` package in cmd with

```
py -m pip install rawpy
```

and it said the requirement was already satisfied, but when I try to import it in python it says:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rawpy'
```

How do I install this I am not too experienced in python btw.

Comment: Hi Dan, which version of rawpy are you trying to install? On which version of Python?

Comment: python 3.8 and the latest verison of rawpy which is rawpy 0.15.0

Comment: It seems that rawpy hasn't been released as binary wheel for Python 3.8 yet, only for Cython, Python 3 | 3.5 | 3.6 | 3.7 (Source: https://pypi.org/project/rawpy/)

Did you try downgrading to python 3.7 to try it ? It might be a compatibility problem.

Comment: @GuiFalourd What makes you think rawpy hasn't been released as binary wheel for 3.8? Also, what is a "Cython" release? rawpy does have binary wheels for Python 3.5 to 3.8 currently.

Comment: Hi letmaik. When looking at https://pypi.org/project/rawpy/ , the Python 3.8 doesn't appear on the Programming Language list. Regarding Cyphon, it's one of the programming language informed there as well (https://pypi.org/search/?c=Programming+Language+%3A%3A+Cython)